# What is NLL in MC of SM/BSM?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, simulations

I know that NLO represents using Next to Leading Order Feynman diagrams for a more accurate calculation. And similarly NNLO being Next to Next to Leading Oder. I am wondering what NLL is an acronym for and it's physics significance.

Answer (score 2):

Without further context for your question it is hard to be sure, but I have seen this abbreviation used for

*Next to Leading Log*

For example, the leading divergence to self energies or running of coupling constants is often logarithmic, and one might be interested in the next to leading order contribution to some approximation. The next to leading g order could be a lower power of coupling into the same logarithm.