# NLO and NLL difference

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, definition, feynman-diagrams

The next-to-leading order (NLO) Feynman diagram is the next leading process having more vertices than the tree-level diagram, but what is next-to-leading-logarithm (NLL)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is NLL in MC of SM/BSM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426486/)

Comment: Hi Dvjj, thanks a lot for referring to this question, however the answer is not clear I'm afraid.